# Knockoutjs referencing Objects from Ids

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have some json data looks like this:

```
var data = {
    Allergens: [{
            Id: 10,
            Label: 'Label 1',
            IconUrl: 'http://www.xyz.de/hello.png'
        }, {
            Id: 12,
            Label: 'Label 2',
            IconUrl: 'http://www.xyz.de/cu.png'
        }
    ],
    Day: {
        Items: [{
            AllergenIds: [10, 12],
            ExternalName: [{
                lang: 'de-DE',
                val: 'Ice Cream Vanilla (item 1)'
            }]
        }, {
            AllergenIds: [10],
            ExternalName: [{
                lang: 'de-DE',
                val: 'Ice Cream Strawberry (item 2)'
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```

Lets say I make a knockout each over my Items.
Each of the Items have a List of `AllergenIds`. 
For these AllergenIds I wanne render another each which contains the Infos/Content of the related `Allergens` Item.

Is there a way to refence theses AllergenIds to the corresponding Allergen Item? So, my desire is when I edit an Allergen, all Items.Allergens will be updated!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to lookup your `Allergens` by `Id`, so I'd start by creating an "index" which can be used later

```
var allergenIndex = data.Allergens.reduce(function(prev,curr){
   prev[curr.Id] = curr;
   return prev;
},{});
```

Then when you loop over your `Day.Items` array, you can find the specific details of each allergen:

```
data.Day.Items.forEach(function(i){
   console.log(i.ExternalName[0].val) 
   i.AllergenIds.forEach(function(a){
       console.log("\tAllergen=" + allergenIndex[a].Label) 
   });
});
```

Output is:

```
Ice Cream Vanilla (item 1)
    Allergen=Label 1
    Allergen=Label 2
Ice Cream Strawberry (item 2)
    Allergen=Label 1
```

Hopefully you can use this to convert over to knockout as appropriate.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7o3Lxcpc/